# db2 timestamp format not loading

Tags: sql, database, datetime, db2

I am trying to bulk-load data with timestamps into DB2 UDB version 9 and it is not working out.

My target table has been created thusly

```
CREATE TABLE SHORT
(
 ACCOUNT_NUMBER INTEGER 
, DATA_UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current timestamp
, SCHEDULE_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current timestamp
...
0)
```

This is the code for my bulk load

```
load from /tmp/short.csv of del modified by COLDEL, savecount 500 messages /users/chris/DATA/short.msg INSERT INTO SHORT NONRECOVERABLE DATA BUFFER 500
```

No rows are loaded. I get an error

```
SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is 
incorrect.  SQLSTATE=22007
```

I tried forcing the timestamp format when I create my table thusly:

```
CREATE TABLE SHORT
(
 ACCOUNT_NUMBER INTEGER 
, DATA_UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' 
, SCHEDULE_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' 
...
0)
```

but to no avail: `SQL0574N  DEFAULT value or IDENTITY attribute value is not valid for column`. Timestamp format in source my data file looks like this

```
2002/06/18 17:11:02.000
```

How can I format my timestamp columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost looks like ISO to me.
If you are able to edit the data file and can safely change the slashes to hyphens, (maybe clip the decimal fraction) and DB2 accepts ISO, you're home.

Comment: You're welcome. If you know your editor, you need no sinkin' DBMS!

Comment: Vi is my friend. And Sed. And Awk.

Comment: Same here. Now go check the timezone ... :-(

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a terrible answer.  "Edit your file" is not the proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [TIMESTAMPFORMAT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0011044.htm) file type modifier for the LOAD utility to specify the format present in your data files.

```
load from /tmp/short.csv
    of del
    modified by COLDEL, TIMESTAMPFORMAT="YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.UUUUUU"
    savecount 500 
    messages /users/chris/DATA/short.msg 
    INSERT INTO SHORT 
    NONRECOVERABLE
```